# C# Wpf Project: Publishing without moving dll

Tags: c#, wpf, publish

I am trying to publish my C# Wpf-Project, which includes 2 (non-framework) dlls **which cannot be moved** (e.g. copied in the directory of my exe).

When I try to execute my program on another computer, with the same dlls in the same directory, my program does not work.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Greetings

Comment: `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy` in reference?

Comment: Do you have an error message you can post? Maybe something from the EventViewer, or your own logging?

Comment: You are referencing them from somewhere on your computer? If so Visual Studio will move a copy of them into the bin folder with your exe. You can't use dll's outside of your bin folder without jumping through some extra steps to configure probing paths - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "non-framework" DLLs you mean `COM-based` DLLs, then you need to register them with `regsvr32.exe` before your program will be able to find them for use.

[How to use the Regsvr32 tool and troubleshoot Regsvr32 error messages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873)